# Follow-up Fixed Payment at Default - Pricing

Tags: finance-mathematics

This question is a follow-up of this question [Fixed Payment at Default - Pricing](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75642/fixed-payment-at-default-pricing) for more clarity.

Starting from the following expression of payoff:

$$
D(0,T) = E(\exp(-\int_{0}^{\tau} r(t)dt) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq T\}})
$$

and knowing that
$$
\text{Probability}(T \leq \tau \leq T+dT) = \lambda(T) \cdot \exp(-\int_{0}^{T} \lambda(t)dt) \cdot dT
$$
we aim to arrive to:

$$
D(0,T) = E(\int_{0}^{T} \lambda(t) \cdot \exp(-\int_{0}^{t} (r(s)+\lambda(s))ds)dt)
$$

The idea as stated is to integrate the payoff over all possible times of default, thus form 0 to T.

We thus have:
$$
D(0,T) = E(\int_{0}^{T} \exp(-\int_{0}^{t} r(s)ds) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{t \leq T\}}dt \mid \mathcal{F}_0)
$$
But I am struggling from this step to develop the calculus. Would the law of iterated expectation be needed?

Comment: amdopt was kind enough to convert your unreadable previous post to mathJax. This time I'd say this is your task.

Comment: The seminal article where you can find those proofs in D. Lando, On Cox processes and credit risky securities. [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226786879_On_Cox_Processes_and_Credit_Risky_Securities).

Comment: Ty for your answer!
As we know

$$
\[
\mathcal{F}_t = \mathcal{G}_t \cup \mathcal{H}_t
\]
$$

Where processes relevant in determining values for spot rate and hazard rate of default are adapted to $$ \mathcal{G}_t$$ 
and $$
\mathcal{H}_t
$$ hold the information of wether there has been a default at time t.

Comment: I don't get the proof 3.4: $$E\left(\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \geq T\}} \, \bigg| \, \mathcal{G}_T \cup \mathcal{H}_t\right) = \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}} \cdot \exp\left(-\int_t^T \lambda_s \, ds\right)$$

What is the point between $$\{\tau > t\}$$ being an atom, and the following equality:
$$E\left(\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \geq T\}} \, \bigg| \, \mathcal{G}_T \cup \mathcal{H}_t\right) = \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}} \cdot E\left(\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \geq T\}} \, \bigg| \, \mathcal{G}_T \cup \mathcal{H}_t\right)$$

Comment: You can pull out $1_{\{\tau>t\}}$ from the conditional expectation because it is ${\cal H}_t$-measurable and $1_{\{\tau\ge T\}}=1_{\{\tau\ge T\}}1_{\{\tau>t\}}\,.$
A lot of insight into Lando's approach is gained from the fact that if we knew the entire path up to $T$ of the ${\cal G}_T$-measurable random variable $\exp(-\int_t^T\lambda_s\,ds)$ then we knew the survival probability  until $T$ conditional on survival until $t\,.$ Lando's equations are a formalization of this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not sure about that!

I just rewrite here my second question as it had a small error on it.

I am just wondering how to go from:
$$
\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau > t\}} \cdot E\left(\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \geq T\}} \, \bigg| \, \mathcal{G}_T \cup \mathcal{H}_t\right)
$$

To:
$$
\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \geq T\}} \cdot \frac{P(\{\tau \geq T\} \cap \{\tau > t\} \,|\, \mathcal{G}_T)}{P(\{\tau > t\} \,|\, \mathcal{G}_T)}
$$

I tried to turn it into all directions but can't see any "obvious" reason for this equality

Comment: Would anyone have an answer on this? Otherwise I will create another subject to try and have an answer on it.

Comment: Not sure why anyone should have the obligation to have an answer on this. Possible hint: $\{\tau>t\}$ is an atom of ${\cal H}_t\,.$ It looks like Lando uses an analogy by which the conditional expectation of $1_B$ w.r.t. a finitely generated $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ can be written as the finite sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n1_{A_i}\mathbb P(B|A_i)$$ where $\mathbb P(B|A_i)=\mathbb P(B\cap A_i)/\mathbb P(A_i)\,.$

Comment: "Not sure why anyone should have the obligation to have an answer on this.": Never said or suggested anything like that but thank you very much for your help.